# Update SQL database with star rating from jsp

Tags: javascript, mysql, ajax, jsp, servlets

I use jsp to present some dat retrieved from user query. Each time the query is input, some contextual data and the query itself is saved on a MySQL db by jdbc. I would add the possibility for the user to rate each result and I've made a rating system which would represent the rating in the form of numbers which are inserted in the db as the user clicks on the numbered star (e.g.** ***** ****corresponds to 2 5 4).
To do so I have in my jdbc this code:

```js
PreparedStatement preps = null;

            preps = dbMySqlConn.prepareStatement("" +
                    " UPDATE " + dbName + "." + tableNameOutput +
                    " SET" + " ratings = ?" +
                    " WHERE id = " + queryID , Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            if (stars != null) {
                preps.setString(19, stars);
            }

            preps.execute();
```

and in the main jsp I visualize the rating system through:

```js
"    <form name=\"rating\"\">\n" +  

"    <input class=\"star star-5\" id=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-5\" type=\"radio\" onClick=\"javascript:saveRating()\" name=\"star\"/>\n" +
"           <label class=\"star star-5\" for=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-5\" title=\"Perfect match\"></label>\n" +
"    </input>" +

"    <input class=\"star star-4\" id=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-4\" type=\"radio\" onClick=\"javascript:saveRating()\" name=\"star\"/>\n" +
"           <label class=\"star star-4\" for=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-4\" title=\"Excellent match\"></label>\n" +
"    </input>" +

"    <input class=\"star star-3\" id=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-3\" type=\"radio\" onClick=\"javascript:saveRating()\" name=\"star\"/>\n" +
"           <label class=\"star star-3\" for=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-3\" title=\"Good match\"></label>\n" +
"    </input>" +

"    <input class=\"star star-2\" id=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-2\" type=\"radio\" onClick=\"javascript:saveRating()\" name=\"star\"/>\n" +
"           <label class=\"star star-2\" for=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-2\" title=\"Fair match\"></label>\n" +
"    </input>" +

"    <input class=\"star star-1\" id=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-1\" type=\"radio\" onClick=\"javascript:saveRating()\" name=\"star\"/>\n" +
"           <label class=\"star star-1\" for=\"star" + sessionTime + i + "-1\" title=\"Wrong match\"></label>\n" +
"    </input>" +

"  </form>\n" +
```

which calls a javascript function whic is:

```js
"   function saveRating(){\n" +

                    "if ($('.star.star-5')[0].checked){" +          
                        "alert(\"Rating 5 saved\");" +
                    "}" +

                    "if ($('.star.star-4')[0].checked){" +
                        "alert(\"Rating 4 saved\");" +
                    "}" +

                    "if ($('.star.star-3')[0].checked){" +
                        "alert(\"Rating 3 saved\");" +
                    "}" +

                    "if ($('.star.star-2')[0].checked){" +
                        "alert(\"Rating 2 saved\");" +
                    "}" +

                    "if ($('.star.star-1')[0].checked){" +
                        "alert(\"Rating 1 saved\");" +
                    "}" +

                    "else{" +
                    "}" +
                    "        }\n" +
                    "</script>" +
```

which works quite fine displaying the alerts, but if I replace the alerts with what it is meant to do, the jdbc insert:

```js
"MySqlJDBC.rate(servletPath, \"1\");"
"MySqlJDBC.rate(servletPath, \"2\");"
"MySqlJDBC.rate(servletPath, \"3\");"
"MySqlJDBC.rate(servletPath, \"4\");"
"MySqlJDBC.rate(servletPath, \"5\");"
```

it just doesn't work and I was asking myself why the alert do work why the calling of the java method does not.

Comment: because javascript runs in the browser and your java code does not. You need to use ajax to make an HTTP request at your servlet (probably running in tomcat), which then takes care to invoke the java code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved within the jsp with code:

```html
"if ($('.star.star-1')[0].checked){" +
                    "   $.ajax({" +
                    "       type: \"POST\"," +
                    "       url: \"" + servletPath + "/servletName\"," +                                      
                    "       data: { operation: \"operation1\", userRating:stars, resId: numberOfQuery }" +    
                    "   }).done(function() {" +
                    "       alert( \"Success\");" +                                         
                    "   });" +
                    "   }" +
```

and making a doPost within the servlet which calls the SQL statement.

The correct flow is:
jsp markup -> jsp function which calls ajax -> servlet doPost -> JDBC